# Windows Mobile device incompatibilities - need suggestions for how to approach testing

Tags: testing, windows-mobile, device-emulation

I have a user who runs my application on a Samsung BlackJack with WM 6.1. He reports issues, like labels not appearing on forms, that I cannot reproduce on any of the emulators or the device that I am developing with (T-Mobile Shadow and WM 6.0).

What are my options to reproduce and identify issues like that, without getting any offending device myself and trying it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

screen sizes are different. The resolutions may also be different. Microsoft has emulators for square pdas and vga resolution pdas. Using the Anchor property of labels might help.

The [Windows Mobile 6 Professional and Standard Software Development Kits Refresh](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=06111A3A-A651-4745-88EF-3D48091A390B&displaylang=en) contains the following emulators:

```
*  Windows Mobile 6 Standard SDK
      o Windows Mobile 6 Standard (176x220 pixels - 96 dpi)
      o Windows Mobile 6 Standard Landscape QVGA (240x320 pixels - 131 dpi)
      o Windows Mobile 6 Standard QVGA (320x240 pixels - 131 dpi)

* Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK
      o Windows Mobile 6 Classic (240x320 pixels - 96 dpi)
      o Windows Mobile 6 Professional (240x320 pixels - 96 dpi)
      o Windows Mobile 6 Professional Square (240x240 pixels - 96 dpi)
      o Windows Mobile 6 Professional Square QVGA (320x320 pixels - 128 dpi)
      o Windows Mobile 6 Professional Square VGA (480x480 pixels - 192 dpi)
      o Windows Mobile 6 Professional VGA (480x640 pixels - 192 dpi)
```

Comment: I am using docking and the forms look fine on all emulator resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

If the emulators don't help, perhaps make a build with more logging built in and give it to the user.  Chances are if they reported the bug, they'll be willing to help a little and send you some logs from that private build.  In the case of a UI glitch though, I'm not sure what logging would help.

Answer (score 0):

This true that my application works well on all other emulators even the Square emulators. But I am getting scroll bar on SQUARE screen with 128 DPI (320 x 320). Other square screens are fine.

I thik this is because how it is rounding the size of the controls when it scales. That is 128/96 = 1.3333. Reduce the control size or compact it when you see these 128DPI 320/320 square screen. (This is Square QVGA).